# How will you invoke other apps from the native iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ipad

How can I invoke an app from a native app? I want to invoke my app on clicking a mail from the native mail app. For example native mail app list staza app and good writer app when you want to view a pdf file, that is in your inbox.

So what we should do if we want to display our app also in that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try inter-process communication. Here is [some guide](http://mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/)

Comment: the example given is for url types,ie it works in safari.what value i should set in info plist for pdf.and how to set the uti "com.adobe.pdf " to it.

Comment: From what I remember, if you click on a url in the email app, then it will redirect you to safari. So, you have 2 ways: 1st: you can hard code the urls inside the email (I am not sure, I didn't try), 2nd: give your website urls, when safari ask for your website, redirect them to a url, that can open your app

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, you have an application on iphone already and you want to open it from email app, is it right?